# DDH, CDH and discrete logarithm assumptions

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

When we consider a group generation algorithm $\mathcal{G}$ (taken from Katz and Lindell's *Introduction to Modern Cryptography*), that takes as input a security parameter $1^n$ and outputs $(\mathbb{Z}_n, n, g)$, where $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an additive group, can we say that the DDH, CDH, and discrete logarithm assumptions hold?

On the other hand, if they don't hold for any $g$, which conditions do we need to assert on the generator?

Comment: None of the assumptions DDH, CDH or DLog are true in $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$; if you need those, you need to use a different group

Comment: @poncho thank you for helping. I still don't fully understand how we can compute the discrete logarithm for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in polynomial time. According to the book, it relies on the definition of a multiplicative group.

Comment: What my comments was based on was your text "... where $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an additive group".  It is quite unusual to represent $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ as an additive group (that is, you use the group operation syntax $A+B$, which is commonly implemented as $A \times B \bmod n$); the other alternative is the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$ (where the above problems are easily solvable in polynomial time)